# React Webpack proces.env.PUBLIC_URL is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In my React app, I have added console in src/index.js for process.env as below;

```
proces.env.PUBLIC_URL // undefined
proces.env.NODE_ENV // "development"
```

I am not sure why proces.env.PUBLIC_URL is coming as undefined. Anything specific I need to check in my app. I have the webpack config below.

config/webpack.dev.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const common = require('./webpack.common');
const srcDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  entry: {
    main: ['react-hot-loader/patch', path.join(srcDirectory, 'index.js')]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
     
    }
  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },

  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|.ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'resolve-url-loader',
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: 'src',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true
    },
    stats: 'minimal',
    overlay: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      },
      '/actuator/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },

  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
});
```

Also below is config/webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const srcDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');
const srcDirectory1 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/public');
const distDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['whatwg-fetch',  'raf/polyfill']
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: [srcDirectory, 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.html', '.scss', '.css']
  },

  output: {
    path: distDirectory,
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|.ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
         test: /\.txt$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: 'raw-loader' 
      },
     
      
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: path.join(srcDirectory, 'images'), to: 'images' }
      ]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(srcDirectory, 'index.html') })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use webpack [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/).

```
plugins: [
  // ...
  new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'DEBUG']),
]
```

Comment: Thanks...so you mean replace the one I have...there are 3 diff entries in my webpack config for plugins

Comment: Add it to the common, if you want it to be available in development and production.

Comment: @copenndthagen don't replace your plugins, just add a comma after the last one and add this new plugin.

Comment: Oh k...sure...let me try adding this and see if I get proces.env.PUBLIC_UR

Comment: It does not work...I am getting NODE_ENV env variable is undefined and DEBUG env variable is undefined

Comment: Also just to reiterate, I was alread seeing proces.env.NODE_ENV // "development", but not able to see proces.env.PUBLIC_URL // undefined

Comment: Do you have the PUBLIC_URL added to your OS env variables? or at least adding it to the start script like `PUBLIC_URL=http://whatever npm run dev` ?

Comment: Nope..I have it at neither place...I was thinking PUBLIC_URL should be coming out of the box somewhere from React...Is that not true ?

Comment: @copenndthagen from _React_? No. You may be confusing that with Create React App: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system.

Comment: So you mean, because I am using webpack here (and that is why CRA does not come into picture and replace the PUBLIC_URL)...and so, we have to pass PUBLIC_URL manually ?

Comment: @copenndthagen CRA also uses Webpack. CRA manages a whole bunch of configuration across Webpack, Babel, ESLint, Jest, etc., so you don't have to. If you _don't_ use it, you can't assume all the things it does will magically appear. Brief research on process.env and Webpack would have pointed you to the relevant plugins: DefinePlugin, EnvironmentPlugin, etc., or you could eject a vanilla CRA app to compare with what you have.

Comment: So I just updated to "build": "set PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:3000/ && react-scripts build",
But still in my rendered index.html, I see as <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">